# I need just the count of unique phone numbers in my mySql table. How do I do that?

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL table with list of people and phone numbers. There are some repeats in these phone numbers. 
I don't want to remove the duplicates based on the phone numbers as a same phone number is related to more that one entity. I just want the count of unique phone numbers in the phone number column. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

I think this is what you are looking for??

Comment: @Marco This might be a silly question..but how do you do the formatting over here?

Comment: When you are writing an answer you have a toolbar. Use curly brackets to convert some text in a code section.

Answer (score 2):

I might be simplifying this a bit..

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT phonenumber)
FROM yourtable;
```